# C# Winforms Application open crystal reports stored in an S3 Bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, crystal-reports

I have a C# Winforms application which is currently able to show crystal reports in the crystal reports viewer.  The reports are stored on a file server, and I use the path to the reports to open them in the application.  All works, no problems.

I have been tasked with moving the report files to an S3 bucket, and loading them from there....

Is this going to be possible?  The only thing I can think to do is download the files on demand and run them from the local directory... but not sure this is the best way to go about this....

Any help much appreciated?!